# Better to use Hashbangs or History API with history.js for single-page application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, single-page-application, history.js, hashbang

The way I see it, it seems like hashbangs were a 'hacky' fix that actually do quite well! However, it seems like the History API (pushstate popstate) is the RIGHT way to make a single page application and is actually reasonable now that History.js provides such a clean/simple framework for states.

I know the largest issue:

1) Backwards compatibility issues with History API - HTML 4 browsers cannot utilize the History API. However, history.js has that solved now, as it automatically converts to be compatible with HTML 4 browsers (changes to hashes).

I know this is a debate that changes by the month like any programming debate, but as of April 2015 which is the better option? And which is more likely to withstand the test of time? I am currently using History.js with my single page application, however my management is somewhat skeptical and prefers hashbangs. Any input?

Comment: Actually the hashbang was introduced explicitly to make pages SEO-friendly. That's the single reason for its existence, literally the entire point of using it.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I was confused. Edited to exclude that issue.